# Is it possible to use all.equal to look at row by row comparisons in R?

Tags: r, rows

I have two different data tables with an average column, `endosperm$AVG` and `seedcoat$AVG`. I have tried to compare them using `all.equal`, but that seems to compare everything and does not compare row by row.

My goal is to find if the row 1 averages from both columns are nearly equal, then repeat for row 2, etc.

There is other data in the dataset that will be useful (the gene name for each row) so I don't want to create a dataframe of just the two AVG columns.

so far what I have is:

```
all.equal(endosperm$AVG, seedcoat$AVG, tolerance=0.5)
```

However this just yields:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Is there a way to run `all.equal` by row?

Comment: `apply( cbind( endosperm$AVG , seedcoat$AVG), 1, all.equal,  tolerance=0.5)` although that seems to be a fairly generous tolerance. Or  `abs(endosperm$AVG - seedcoat$AVG) < 0.5`

Comment: rawr, your command worked very well, thank you.

Comment: BondedDust, I am starting with a high tolerance, but will be refining it based on the results of the first run.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sel <- abs(endosperm$AVG-seedcoat$AVG)<=0.5
endosperm[sel,]
seedcoat[sel,]
```